# How to put an image in a table created by FPDF?

Tags: php, xampp, fpdf

I have following code:

```
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(60,65, $enteredText ,1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(60,65,$enteredText2,1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(60,65,$enteredText3,1,1,'C');
```

I would love to put an image as the background of my created Cells (of my table). For each cell, a own image.

I can't find any good information to this online. I only found how to change colour in the background from this source:

http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/setfillcolor.htm

```
SetFillColor(int r [, int g, int b])
```

But I can't really put an image in the background with the method SetFillColor. Does anyone know how I could do this? I aprecciate your help!

Comment: Call `Image()` before `Cell()`.